# MsBuild Task for Jetbrains dotCover on CruiseControl.net

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, dotcover

We're using CruiseControl.net and I'm trying to make the build fail if total test coverage calculated by [JetBrains dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) is lower than certain number X.

is there an MsBuild task for this? I can only find examples using TeamCity, which we aren't. :(
is generating report and reading the coverage percentage value from it my only option here?

Comment: If there is none or you don't want to wait, http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/289643, you can always write your own.

Comment: Make the jump to Teamcity. You know it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I ended up jumping to NCover instead. It meets all our requirements: http://docs.ncover.com/how-to/continuous-integration/cruisecontrol-net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an official confirmation dotCover MsBuild task is not out yet, I hope this helps someone not waist time looking for it:

> From: Support - Fedor Buyvol-Kot [mailto:support@jetbrains.com]  Sent:
>   11 June 2012 17:55 Cc: support@jetbrains.com Subject: Re: [ dotCover -
>   Technical Support ]
>
> Hi,
>
> This feature is in our plans, but currently there is no precise
>   estimate for its implementation. You are welcome to monitor its status
>   in our bug-tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-2386
>
> Regards.